# Projection of a point to a line segment Python Shapely

Tags: python, gis, point, projection, shapely

I have a LineString defined by two points, so essentially a straight line segment, and I wanted to project a point on to it. I am aware of `.project` and `.interpolate`. However when the point is "outside" the segment, I don't want the closest point on the segment, but I want to extend the segment and draw a line going through the point and is orthogonal to the (extended) line segment. I want the coordinate of the projection.

[image]

For example if the point is "within" the segment

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import LineString
point = Point(0.2, 0.5)
dist = LineString([(0, 1), (1, 1)]).project(point)
list(LineString([(0, 1), (1, 1)]).interpolate(dist).coords)
```

Anyone knows what to do when the point is outside of the segment?

Comment: Are you interested in primitive solutions that do the vector arithmetic manually?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It will be probably easiest to do this manually. If you denote the angle `x - u - v` as `alpha`, then

```
cos(alpha) = (v - u).(x - u) / (|x - u|*|v - u|)
```

where `.` denotes the dot product, and `| |` represents the Euclidean norm.
The distance `d` of `P(x)` from `u` is therefore:

```
d = cos(alpha)*|x - u| = (v - u).(x - u) / |v - u|
```

Having calculated `d`, the projected point `P(x)` is then easily obtained as:

```
P(x) = u + d*(v - u)/|v - u|
```

The implementation:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import LineString

point = Point(0.2, 0.5)
line = LineString([(0, 1), (1, 1)])

x = np.array(point.coords[0])

u = np.array(line.coords[0])
v = np.array(line.coords[len(line.coords)-1])

n = v - u
n /= np.linalg.norm(n, 2)

P = u + n*np.dot(x - u, n)
print(P) #0.2 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider using [`scikit-spatial`](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-spatial/) as follows:

```py
from skspatial.objects import Line

line = Line.from_points(point_a=[0,1], point_b=[1,1])
point = (1.2, 0.5) # example of a point not "within" the line segment

projected_point = line.project_point(point)


print(projected_point)
```

Output:

```
[1.2 1. ]
```